# Add a character to a string every time I run the code

Tags: java

I am learning Java at the moment, but I'm facing a problem.
I want to make it that every time I run my code, it adds a character to a string.

This is what I have at this moment:

```
StringBuilder amountReady = new StringBuilder();
amountReady.append("|");
```

But when I run this code for the second time, it forgets all about the first "|", and just starts over with one "|" instead of two.

Thanks in advance,

~Rik

Comment: You are creating a new object every time.

Comment: Also, by "every time I run my code", do you mean multiple method calls within one program, or multiple runnings of a program? One of those is much easier than the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting your `amountReady` to a `new StringBuilder()` object every time your run this code. A `new` StringBuilder is empty by default.

Instead, put the line: `StringBuilder amountReady = new StringBuilder();` outside the method that appends to it... this way, the `amountReady` variable will already exist, and you can just append to it as you have.

Comment: No you should probably not do that since `StringBuilder` is not thread safe. If thread safety could be compromised, use a `StringBuffer` instead.

Comment: @MartinAndersson Well, it sounds like the OP is relatively new to Java, so the program is probably going to be single-threaded. A good point to note though.

Comment: he makes no mention of threads, and simply putting the `StringBuilder` in the class header does not inherently make it non-thread safe.

Comment: Have you ever spent time with inexperienced programmers? I do that every day. Giving them bad practices at the start of their career is not a good idea. Even though I understand your point, I still have to argue differently. Only local fields in a method is guaranteed to be thread safe. They are put on the executing Thread's stack.

Comment: well, then you may want to get to re-writing the OP's entire project, since in order to be thread safe, his classes need to be built in a specific way. It's a design to structure your program to be thread safe. Not all programs need threads (most don't actually). So, at this point in the OP's java career, throwing new lingo and threads at him is only going to confuse. Even text books don't introduce threading concepts until you are already advanced and know what you are doing mostly.

Comment: I whole-heatedly agree with you about not giving learners bad practices -- because they tend to stick and is hard to combat later on. But in this case, it wasn't the OP's intention to make his program thread-safe.

Comment: @MartinAndersson Touché ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the reserved word "new" you're creating a new object. Each time you execute the code above, you create a new object (so old objects that could be stored in amountReady are dellocated from memory) and make it store one single character.

If your question is about if whenever you execute a java application objects from old executions are still in memory answer is absolutely not.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be kept between individual runs of the program you would need to write it out to a file or database and read it back in each time.

A file would be easier for a small exercise like this for sure.  Java has quite nice support for filesystems.  Google for "java File" and take a look.  It's simple to implement and there are many examples here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/XjHKwb  Check this; you may not need a method as appendString; you can add entire code into main method.  We can remove static etc., etc, I am just giving an idea that works.

```
private static StringBuilder amountReady = new StringBuilder();
public static String appendString(String str)
{
    amountReady.append(str);
    return amountReady.toString();
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    System.out.println(appendString("|"));
}
```

Comment: You should never ever add `throws Exception` to a method. Can you mention a method that does not do that already in Java? Indeed you add nothing of value. But what you do is effectively destroying all chances your IDE have to inform you of unhandled exceptions thrown by code in your method. There's only one exception to this rule: If what I told you is what you want. It could be the case for instance if you write a unit test method that expects an exception to be thrown.